# How has Raya been searching for Sisu for 6 years?

Tags: plot-explanation, raya-and-the-last-dragon

In "Raya and the Last Dragon", Naamari says that Raya stole the map of Sisu's location a few months before we see Raya on-screen 6 years after the world broke. How is this possible when Raya mentions that she has been searching for 6 years for Sisu? Was she not using the map the whole time? From the clip where she is circling the last destination, it appears she has been to all other locations. Did she just visit them in the last few months?

Comment: While no one seems to know, I think she used memory from looking at the map before. She definitely seemed to not draw lots of attention b/c Naamari thought she was dead (until the map was missing). But for the final location, it seems that Raya didn't know where to look and was desperate for the map. Or it's possible that she attempted looking for 6 years without the map and didn't make much progress so in a moment of desperation stole the map several months ago and checked all those spots within the last few months. @Disney, I would like to see a series of what happened during these 6 years.